# Trying to use a single button function to add playlist from an array to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Assuming you have an array of an object coming from database (say songs) and it was rendered using the v-for.
i want to create a button with a function to add each object song to another component. having it in mind that i don't know the object keys because i don't know how many objects there are in that array.
Also having it in mind that the button was added to each list using the same v-for

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Vue Top 20 Artists</h1>
      <ul>
      <li class="list" v-for="(artist, x) in artists" :key="x">
        <h3>{{artist.name}}</h3>
        <button @click="addPlayList()">Add to playlist</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  props: ["artists"],
  methods:{
    addPlayList(){
    let hey = this.artists
    alert(Object.keys(hey))
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What a about useing the artist as argument for your method:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Vue Top 20 Artists</h1>
      <ul>
      <li class="list" v-for="(artist, x) in artists" :key="x">
        <h3>{{artist.name}}</h3>
        <button @click="addPlayList(artist)">Add to playlist</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  props: ["artists"],
  methods:{
    addPlayList(artist){
      alert(artist)
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

if you want to transfer the clicked button to the parent element use `this.$emit()` explained in detail: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Answer (score 0):

If the 'other component' is your child component you will most likely pass your list as a prop. If it is your parent, then you could emit it together with a custom event. And you would use Vuex to share your list 'globally'. Though anyway before passing it to somewhere else, first you have to prepare your playlist in your current component. You can add a 'playlist' to your `data` like: `data: () => ({ playlist: [] })`

Your function would then push a new artist to the 'playlist'. 
You can pass the `artist` to your function like: `@click="addPlayList(artist)"`

So in case your 'other component' is your child it could look like this:

```html
<template>
<div>
<h1>Vue Top 20 Artists</h1>
  <ul>
  <li class="list" v-for="(artist, x) in artists" :key="x">
    <h3>{{artist.name}}</h3>
    <button @click="addPlayList(artist)">Add to playlist</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<some-component :playlist="playlist" />
</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import 'SomeComponent' form '....'
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  components: { SomeComponent },
  props: ["artists"],
  data: () => ({ playlist })
  methods:{
    addPlayList (artist) {
      this.playlist.push(artist)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*If it is a parent component* `addPlayList` function could look like:

```js
addPlayList (artist) {
  this.playlist.push(artist)
  this.$emit('some-event', this.playlist)
}
```